# How to not set image field as null when PUT/Patch in Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a website that has users each user has his own profile, the problem is when the user wants for example edit his email or username and save this appear `profile_image: The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.` I thought that the frontend problem and I tried to edit the user username field without touch the image field in the Django rest framework API screen but it shows the same problem the user image field has a path to his image in getting but in put the image input is empty, how I can get edit the user other fields without loss the user image

my view

```
class UserProfileRetrieveUpdate(generics.GenericAPIView):
serializer_class = UserProfileChangeSerializer
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = UserProfileChangeSerializer(
            instance=request.user)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user_profile_serializer = UserProfileChangeSerializer(
            instance=request.user,
            data=request.data,
    )
    if user_profile_serializer.is_valid():
        user_profile_serializer.save()
        print(user_profile_serializer.data)
        return Response(user_profile_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    errors = dict()
    errors.update(user_profile_serializer.errors)
    return Response(errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My serializer

```
class UserProfileChangeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
profile_image = serializers.ImageField()
class Meta:
    model = Account
    fields = ('pk', 'email', 'username', 'UserFullName', 'bio', 'profile_image')
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to approach this problem.

##### A. Add a PATCH request to the class `UserProfileRetrieveUpdate` in your view.

The slight difference between the PUT and PATCH request can solve the problem.

###### The difference between PUT and PATCH request.

With **PUT** request, the client is requesting a full update to the resource and hence must send all the values for the attributes of a model class. Thus, the new instruction replaces the previous one completely. Missing out on certain key value pairs in the request, would lead to setting the default values assigned in the model class.

With **PATCH** request, the client is requesting a partial update to the resource and hence shall send only the values for the attributes of a model class that need updating. Thus, the new instruction updates the previous instruction with the received key value pairs in the request.

Hence, if we use the PATCH request, then there would be no need to send the `profile_image` data and still it will remain preserved.

###### Suggested Code

A new method `patch` needs to be added to the class `UserProfileRetrieveUpdate` in your view, and the `user_profile_serializer` shall be assigned with attribute `partial=True` to the `UserProfileChangeSerializer` as it indicates that there will be partial updating of data instead of the default, which is full  updating.

```
def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user_profile_serializer = UserProfileChangeSerializer(
        instance=request.user,
        data=request.data,
        partial=True
    )
    if user_profile_serializer.is_valid():
        user_profile_serializer.save()
        return Response(user_profile_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(user_profile_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

##### B. Modify `models.py`

This section entails additional changes that can help improve the code.
To accommodate these solutions, edit the class `UserProfile` in the models.py file.

###### 1. Keep in mind

**DON'T** ever set ImageField with `null=True` as Django stores the path from `MEDIA_ROOT` to file/image in a CharField.

###### 2. Setting imagefield as optional

If the ImageField can be optional, then set the attribute `blank=True` as it will allow empty values in the database.

```
profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image_directory', blank=True)
```

*Please Note:* image_directory is the path directly in `MEDIA_ROOT`.

###### 3. Setting a default image *(only beneficial for POST request)*

If there is a default image that can be set when no image path is passed to the ImageField, then set the attribute `default=default.jpg`. This is beneficial for POST requests with no value passed to the `profile_image` as it will set its path to `default.jpg`.

```
profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image_directory', default=default.jpg)
```

*Please Note:* default.jpg path must exist in the `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this qustion by 1- remove the `profile_image = serializers.ImageField()` from the serializer 2- I added this function to the `UserProfileChangeSerializer` this can get the user profile image url

```
 def get_profile_image_url(self, obj):
    return obj.profile_image.url
```